# Customising the voice in Text-to-Speech

Tags: java, c++, text-to-speech

Is there any open source project or library (in java or c++) that i can use to convert text to a user voice.
what i mean is that, the user can train the system to use a particular voice not the voice that came with the application when converting a text to speech.

Comment: Many will let you tweak vocal parameters and pronunciations to some degree. None that I know of will reliably imitate a specific person.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the biggest TTS engines allow you to adapt the voice or train the voice from speaker-specific data, so your voice will not be distinguishable from the speaker.

Check these toolkits:

http://mary.dfki.de/

http://festival.org

http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp/

HTS has the strongest voice adaptation framework, you can check speaker-adaptive training demo here:

http://hts.sp.nitech.ac.jp/?Download